# Django: URL with RegEx for query params

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm having difficulties using RegEx with Django-Urls.

Given a string and two integers, `s, i1, i2`, I want to create the following url:

`/s/?pagem=i1&pagec=i2`

Then, from inside of the correnspoding template, I want to create an href, redirecting to the page given `s, i1, i2`. How do I do that?

**urls.py**:

`re_path(r'^<str:s>/(?P<pagem>[0-9]&<pagec>[0-9])/$', view, name='chat-explicit-pag')`

**template**:

`<a href="{% url 'chat-explicit-pag' s i1 i2 %}"`

**which gives**:

```
Reverse for 'chat-explicit-pag' with arguments '('39_41', 1, 1)' not
found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['chat/<str:s>/(?P<i1>[0-9]&<i2>[0-9])/$'].
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The Django URL handler doesn't handle the querystring (the bit after the `?`). If you want to use `/s/?pagem=i1&pagec=i2`, then change the URL pattern to `path('<str:s>/', ...)` and in the template do: `{% url 'chat-explicit-pag' s %}?pagem=i1&pagec=i2`.

Comment: As a separate issue, `re_path(r'^<str:s>, ...)` is a mixture of the `path()` and `re_path()` styles. Pick one approach, you can't mix the two in a single pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently djangos URL-handler can't handle the querystring and i had to do the following:
`{% url 'chat-explicit-pag' s %}?pagem=i1&pagec=i2`.

See @Alasdair 's comment above